# google wallet success callback

Tags: java, grails, google-checkout, android-pay

I am going through [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#3). I want to redirect the page on successful payment using the success handler but I also want to be sure that the payment was successfully processed, which happens by a post back, explained [here](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#5)

I am not sure how to make it synchronously, which means redirect to my controller only after the post back is called by Google! 
Also, how do I test post back with localhost?

Or is there a method which I can call on Google API which will give me status of the transaction?

---EDIT---

I wonder, if google wallet popup only shows success after calling the post back. Even if that's true how do I test it with localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation you linked should already answer your question -

- You will get a postback *(and a **success callback** result in client side)* if Google successfully processed the payment - *`"If you want to make sure that the buyer has paid for the item, you should specify a postback URL. If you do, Google sends an HTTP POST message to the postback URL whenever a purchase completes. Your server needs to acknowledge these POST messages, or else the transactions will be canceled.`* See [**here**](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#5).
- Unsure what you meant by "synchronous" - there is a success and failure callback (client side) that you will write/handle given a result...
- You cannot use `localhost` to handle the callback *from Google* - your handler must be on a *public facing server reachable by public DNS* (the callback request comes from Google - the context of `localhost` will obviously be *their server*).
- the (modal) popup is persistent until either your success or failure client script "takes over" and does what you want it to do

  - note: if your server doesn't handle the callback, Google will display error to the user/buyer as mentioned above....

Hth....

---

Additional reference: see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16885478/304683) - which provides more info on what you can expect from as a RESULT from Google (during payment processing).

Comment: I understand your first point but my question is that I want to make sure that paymey is processed before I redirect to my Download page. So the question phrased differently "Is it guaranteed that google callback will always be called before the JS success handler?" Second, I totally understand I can't use localhost, but if I can't then how do I do the development?

Comment: @Sap - I've modified the answer to be more concise, I left out a section that should clarify re: if the payment fails, the callback result is a failure (client side). Your failure handler should then handle. Debugging: you can use your existing public server to handle sandbox (a setting in the Google Javascript) and/or dedicate a url on your server for debugging (e.g. /debug vs. /live).

Comment: link is no longer working